# 'More than I could have hoped for'

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Consider the below sentence. Context: The speaker came from a very poor background, and has recently received a promotion to become the CEO of a major company; for that reason the speaker is over the moon.

> Is my getting promoted not more than I could ever have hoped for, having come from a very poor background?

I'm having difficulty comprehending the above sentence. Well, I get what the essential meaning of the sentence is - that the speaker is ecstatic about having got the promotion - but an understanding of the syntax eludes me.

It is the following two features of the sentence that are the most confusing to me:

1. 'more than'. What part of speech does 'more' belong to? It cannot be an adverb (as it usually is: cf. *He is more interesting than I will ever be*), because it is not modifying anything else.
2. 'could have hoped for'. What I do not understand here is whether or not this hope was ever felt by him, i.e. whether or not it was actualised. In most sentences containing *could have*, the possibility/ability/etc. is not actualised: e.g. *I could have gone to Germany* (but didn't).

Thank you.

Comment: More coffee would be *more* as an adjective, like here.

Comment: It's the same as "There was more than I thought." Does that make sense? The syntax is a lot clearer, without the negative and other features.

Comment: @StuartF. Your example ('There was more than I thought') appears to be at variance with the analyses of YosefBaskin and MarcInManhattan, who claim that 'more' functions as an adjective here. If what they say is true - if 'more' is indeed an adjective here - then your example, in which 'more' would seem to function as a noun, is not comparable with mine.

Comment: Where did that sentence come from, please? Does it sound natural to you?

Answer (score 0):

1. "More" can be considered either an adjective or a pronoun,<sup>1</sup> functioning in either case as a subject complement. From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/more):

> more adjective
> : GREATER
> // something *more* than she expected

> more pronoun, singular or plural in construction
> : additional persons or things or a greater amount
> // *more* will arrive shortly
> // *more* was spilled

2. No, the hope was not "actualized". The speaker "could have hoped" for something, and getting promoted is apparently "more" than that.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some people might prefer to consider it a noun.

Comment: Right. Suppose the addressee answered with *Yes, this is more than you could have hoped for*. Does 'could' indicate past ability here? I am rather confused as to what the 'could' means here, as to what sense of modality it confers on the hope.

Comment: @Eric It simply refers to possibility. On a scale from 0 to 100, it was only possible for the speaker to hope for something from 0 to 80. This is more than 80.

Answer (score -2):

> Is my getting promoted not more than I could ever have hoped for, having come from a very poor background?

This is a rhetorical question and does not require a question mark. (It is also stilted and pompous.)

What the person wished to convey is

*My getting promoted is more than I could ever have hoped for because I came from a very poor background.*

From this, you can see that "*more*" is an adjectival predicate to "*My getting promoted is*" and "*than I could ever have hoped for*" is adverbial clause modifying "more".